# GameCenter achievement is not completed

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, device, game-center, achievements

I have a rather disturbing problem. When I unlock an achievement, I show a notification about it. It is triggered when `achievement.completed == YES`. On the Simulator, this is ok, `achievement.completed` is `true` and the notification shows. However, on any device this is `false` and no notification is shown! I use the same code, nothing changes, I don't have any `#ifdef`'s for Simulator.

Code:

```
if (achievement.completed) {
    [self showAchievementNotification: [_achievementDescriptions objectForKey:achievement.identifier]];
}
```

I modified the code, so it works now:

```
if (achievement.percentComplete >= 100.0f && percentComplete == achievement.percentComplete) {
    [self showAchievementNotification: [_achievementDescriptions objectForKey:achievement.identifier]];
}
```

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out another way. I edited the question, the last code snippet has the anwser.